# Замена значений в строке и преобразование в массив

Tags: php

Есть строка: `белый, сиреневый, розовый`, нужно сделать что-бы цвета были в HEX.
Делаю так: https://3v4l.org/m87kc
На выходе получаю массив в HEX:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "#fff"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "#C769B5"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "#F2BDCC"
}
```

Это то что нужно, но код получается довольно большим, если учитывать что цветов будет довольно много. Можно ли сделать как-то по другому и уменьшить код?

Comment: чтобы укоротить используйте конструкцию switch - case , а не множественные условия

Comment: @Dmitriy Мне кажется особой разницы нет, просто два различных способа написать то же самое.

Comment: Как вариант - сделать второй массив где ключ это цвет а значение = hex и через тот же foreach подставлять.. уж получше будет чем вручную всё это прописывать

Comment: @InDevX Но строки то разные и цвета в них разные, как сделать массив с нужными значениями?

Comment: Все цвета которые есть в палитре . и от туда уже подтягивать

Comment: Это цвета в товаре, т.е. у одного товара будет строка с одними цветами, у др. уже значения этой строки будет совсем другое.

Comment: в чём проблема, универсальный массив с палитрой делай, а туда уже товар с нужным цветом подставляй!

Comment: @g4343 добавил пример того. что я имел ввиду.. массивы где брать это вам решать.. Можно вручную добавить, можно формировать "автоматически"

Comment: Почему изначально не писать цвета по-английски: `white, violet, pink`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов Потому-то это атрибуты и в карточке товара выводятся словами на Русском.

Comment: Из-за возможности наличия пробелов стоит писать не `explode(',',...)`, а `preg_split('#,\s*#', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showHexColors($colours,$hexColours){
    $colours = explode(",", $colours);
    foreach ($colours as $key => &$val){
        $val = trim($val);
        if (array_key_exists($val, $hexColours)) {
            $val = $hexColours[$val];
        } else {
            $val = false;
        }
    }
    return $colours;
}

$colours = 'синий, красный, белый';
$hex = ['синий' => '#14r23']; 

var_dump( showHexColors($colours,$hex) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы некорректно сплиттите исходную строку. С помощью `preg_split` можно разрешить любое количество пробельных символов вокруг запятой:

```
$str = 'белый, сиреневый, розовый, серобуромалиновый';
$сolours = preg_split("#\s*,\s*#", $str);

$map = [
  'белый' => '#222', 
  'сиреневый' => '#333', 
  'розовый' => '#444',
];
$mapped = array_map(function($color) use($map) { 
  return $map[$color] ?? $color;
}, $сolours);
echo implode(', ', $mapped);
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/RXEis)

Answer (score 0):

```
$сolours = 'синий, белый, красный';

$tu = explode(",", $сolours);

foreach($tu as $key =>$value) {
    $search_array = array('синий' => '#111', 'красный' =>'#222', 'белый'=>'#333');

    $value=str_replace(' ', '', $value);
    if (array_key_exists($value, $search_array)) {
        $color[]=$search_array[$value];
    }
}
    print_r($color);
?>
```

Comment: Выводит только 1 цвет: https://3v4l.org/9RjVd

Comment: $tu=array(синий, красный, белый); foreach($tu as $key =>$value) {$search_array = array('Серый' => '#14r23', 'Чёрный' =>'#4fefewf', 'синий'=>'#dfsfwe', 'красный'=>'#fefwef', 'белый'=>'#fwefwefwe'); // этот массив универсальный
if (array_key_exists($value, $search_array)) {
    $color[]=$search_array[$value];
}} print_r($color);

Comment: Изначально есть строка: `синий, белый, красный`, а не массив, если переделать ее в массив через explode, то выводит только 1 цвет: https://3v4l.org/Y1qeS

Comment: @g4343, вы хотябы прочитали бы про функцию, конечно выведит один цвет, вы же за место ключа значение тулите.

Comment: @g4343, вы некорректно эксплодите - https://3v4l.org/mI5du

Comment: @vp_arth Да, это уже понял) спс.

Answer (score 0):

```
$colours = 'синий, белый, красный, розовый';
$arrColours = explode(",", $colours);
$hex = [
    'синий' => '#fff',
    'белый' => '#000',
    'красный' => '#444',
    'зеленый' => '#333',
];
$result = [];

foreach ($arrColours as $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if (array_key_exists($value, $hex)) {
        $result[] = $hex[$value];
    } else $result[] = false;
}

print_r($result);
```